# Single XML attribute per line in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

Is there any option in Android Studio to enable / disable to have only one XML file attribute in one line?

By default, I have (for instance) 2 or 3 attributes on the same line.
I would like to have only one attribute per line.

How can I achieve that?

My code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But instead I would like to have by default this :

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView 
    android:text="Hello World!" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Definitely more readable for me.

Comment: can you post your XML ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Ctrl+A (Select All) in your XML file.
2. Ctrl+Alt+L (Reformat Code)
   that's it.

Answer (score 2):

If Ctrl+Alt+L doesn't work, check your Settings->Editor->Code Style->XML->Android->Layout Files->Wrap Attributes

Answer (score 1):

Go to File on the top left corner → Settings → Editor → Code Style → XML → Other tab → Wrap Attributes into "Wrap Always" and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

For Windows. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to reformat the code.

For Mac. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to reformat the code.